# Prolog Chaining winners?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to compare two people and from those 2 people if the person had played someone before and won then lost to the newer person then that person technically is above from everyone else.

For example, It's set up like this:

Example of how it's set up: `winner(won, lost).`

```
winner(john, jacob).
winner(mike, john).
winner(scott, mike).
winner(matt, scott).

winner(X, Z) :- winner(X, Y), winner(Y, Z).
```

If I call: `winner(matt, mike).` It'll return true since matt beat scott which means he also beats mike since mike lost to scott.

Essentially I want to be able to call `winner(matt, jacob).` and it'll return true.

I have it only querying on tier down with that current rule, how would I go about querying through unlimited tiers? I'm confused on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two predicates. One for the basic facts, `winner/2`, and another for the transitive relation. For example:

```
transitive_winner(X, Y) :-
    winner(X, Y).
transitive_winner(X, Z) :-
    winner(X, Y),
    transitive_winner(Y, Z).
```

With this definition and your `winner/2` facts, you can ask e.g.

```
?- transitive_winner(mike, Y).
Y = john ;
Y = jacob ;
false.
```

You need to be careful when defining this transitive relations, however, to avoid left-recursion as in:

```
transitive_winner(X, Z) :-
    transitive_winner(Y, Z),
    winner(X, Y).
```

In Prolog systems that don't support *tabling*, a call to `transitive_winner/2` would result in a stack overflow error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I couldn't wrap my head around it, I knew I was close. :)